# Javascript string assignment to key-value string

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var inputString ={"Key1":"Planes","Key2":"Trains","Key3":"Cars","Key4":"Caoch","Key5":"Cycles","Key6":"Bikes"}

var value = inputString ["Key3"];
alert(value);
```

The above code works fine, notice that the variable inputString is assigned everything between the curly braces. I'm a js novice but I think that is a convention to indicate some sort of object. That kind of string assignment looks strange to me, but it works as demonstrated above.

My issue is when I try to assign the variable `inputString` to string literal, as follows:

```
var inputString2 ='{"Key1":"Planes","Key2":"Trains","Key3":"Cars","Key4":"Caoch","Key5":"Cycles","Key6":"Bikes"}'

var value = inputString2 ["Key3"];
alert(value);
```

The above code returns `undefined`, why?

I'm sure someone with a deep understanding of javascript can explain this to me.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to use Object methods with a string?

Comment: You need to use `eval` on that string.... j/k (don't do that) look into json.js http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: this "some sort of object" is actually called an [`object literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), the second one is just a `string literal`, most probably a string dump of a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because it is not object it is just a string.

```
var inputString2 ='{"Key1":"Planes","Key2":"Trains","Key3":"Cars","Key4":"Caoch","Key5":"Cycles","Key6":"Bikes"}'
```

You need to remove quotes around your json. It should be like this.

```
 var inputString2 ={"Key1":"Planes","Key2":"Trains","Key3":"Cars","Key4":"Caoch","Key5":"Cycles","Key6":"Bikes"}
```

If you get it as string. Use JSON.parse

```
 var convertedJson =  JSON.parse(inputString2);
var value = convertedJson ["Key3"];
alert(value);
```

[See JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Hi PSL, is there a way to turn inputString2 from a string into an object, so it can work?

Comment: Use JSON.parse(inputString2)

Comment: Don't wrap the curly braces with quotes.